# Оптимальное количество нейронов/слоев

Tags: нейронные-сети, машинное-обучение, искусственный-интеллект

Потиху изучаю нейронные сети. Принцип я понял, основные понятия вроде бы уловил. Даже самый простой прототипчик написал.

Но вот какой вопрос у меня появился:

*Я вижу, что моя нейронная сеть недостаточно умна, сколько ни обучай, и понимаю, что нужно увеличить количество нейронов. Но каким образом мне увеличивать их количество? Увеличить количество на слое, или же увеличить количество слоёв?*

(Понятное дело, это нужно подбирать **экспериментально**, но из-за отсутствия опыта я не могу ссылаться на свои наблюдения как на валидные, а вопрос мучает уже сейчас).

Если я правильно понимаю, можно представить аналогию с обработкой изображения:

**a)** Допустим, мы изначально работали только с бинарного вида изображением. Ну, белый/чёрный пиксель. А потом хотим обрабатывать обычное черно-белое изображение (или цветное). Количество входных нейронов может не увеличиться, но мы-то понимаем, что усложнился **один шаг**, и поэтому можем добавить дополнительные нейроны в **существующий слой**.

**b)** Мы хотим выделять резкие границы на изображении. Понятное дело, тут уже будет гораздо **больше шагов**, а не один объемный. Тут сначала нужно сделать из цветного изображения черно-белое, потом, к примеру, взять квадрат цвета, ну или что-то подобное, словом, задача не в один шаг. И тут мы уже увеличиваем именно **количество слоёв** в сети.

Верен ли мой ход мысли? Может есть какие-то более конкретные сведения на эту тему, которые я упустил/не нашёл?

**P.S.** ибо стала задача сделать ИИ для простенькой логической игры, и захотелось попробовать заставить компьютер обучаться, играя против компьютера. А так как процесс не быстрый, пытаюсь прикинуть необходимое количество слоёв сети для ИИ этой игры. Сам я пока что расцениваю сложность в пару скрытых слоёв, опираясь лишь на интуицию и примерный ход мыслей человека, играющего в это.

Comment: [Связанный вопрос...](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/181/how-to-choose-the-number-of-hidden-layers-and-nodes-in-a-feedforward-neural-netw)

Comment: @MaxU угу, и правда подобный. Странно, что я не нашёл его. Буду разбираться.